# Get all message from aws sqs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless

I have a `ScheduledEvent` on my `lamda function` for every 24 hours and then inside function, I am calling `SQS` to get my messages.

```
export class EmailNotificationProcessor {
    public static async run(): Promise<void> {
        console.log('event');
        await this.getNotificationFromSqs();
    }

    private static async getNotificationFromSqs(): Promise<void> {
        const messagesToDelete: DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntryList = [];
        const messageRequest: ReceiveMessageRequest = {
            QueueUrl: process.env.DID_NOTIFICATION_SQS_QUEUE,
            MaxNumberOfMessages:10,
            WaitTimeSeconds:20
        }
        const { Messages }: ReceiveMessageResult = await receiveMessage(messageRequest);
        console.log('Messages', Messages);
        console.log('Total Messages ', Messages.length);
        if (Messages && Messages.length > 0) {
            for (const message of Messages) {
                console.log('body is ', message.Body);
                messagesToDelete.push({
                    Id: message.MessageId,
                    ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle,
                } as DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry);
            }
        }
        await deleteMessages(messagesToDelete);
    }
}
```

I am expecting 1 to 30 messages inside my queue and want to process all messages before sending an email which consists of the content that I will parse from `sqs body`.

My function for receiving messages

```
export const receiveMessage = async (request: SQS.ReceiveMessageRequest): Promise<PromiseResult<SQS.ReceiveMessageResult, AWSError>> =>{
    console.log('inside receive');
    return sqs.receiveMessage(request).promise();
}
```

Now I am not able to receive all messages at once and only getting 3 messages or sometimes 1 message at a time.

I know limit for API call is 10 in one single request but is there any way to wait and get all your message.

Comment: You haven't included a question, or a description of a problem. Your post is just a statement about what you are currently doing, without a description of what you need help with.

Comment: @MarkB please read it again i just updated the question and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There's no way to get more than 10 messages in a single API call, and no guarantee you will even get 10. You need to wrap the call to SQS in a loop and keep requesting more messages until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, There is no configuration to get more then 10 messages from queue.

> ReceiveMessage: Retrieves one or more messages (up to 10), from the specified queue

For your other problems: I think you are using **Short poll** ReceiveMessage call.If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, *you might not receive any messages* in a particular ReceiveMessage response.

**Try Long Polling:**
Long polling helps reduce the cost of using Amazon SQS by *eliminating the number of empty responses* *(when there are no messages available for a ReceiveMessage request)* and false empty responses *(when messages are available but aren't included in a response*).

Note* For getting more messages you need to wrap the call to SQS in a loop and keep requesting more messages until the queue is empty, which can lead you to get duplicate messages as well so try VisibilityTimeout in that problem.

**Try VisibilityTimeout:** The duration (in seconds) that the received messages are hidden from subsequent retrieve requests after being retrieved by a ReceiveMessage request.

**Sample Wrap up SQS call code:**

```
function getMessages(params, count = 0, callback) {
let allMessages = [];
sqs.receiveMessage(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err || (data && !data.Messages || data.Messages.length <= 0)) {
        
        if(++count >= config.SQSRetries ){
            return callback(null, allMessages);
        }

        return setTimeout(() => {
            return getMessages(params, count, callback);
        }, 500);
        
    } else if (++count !== config.SQSRetries ){
        allMessages.push(data);

        return setTimeout(() => {
            return getMessages(params, count, callback);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        allMessages.push(data);

    callback(null, allMessages);
    }
});
```

In **config.SQSRetries**, we have set the value according to our requirement but as your SQS have 1 to 30 messages, Then *'7'* will be good for you!

Links: [RecieveMessage UserGuide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html)

Comment: it would be great to add some code in your answer to show how i can wrap call to sqs and i am using long pooling please look again at my question

Comment: The answer is updated with sample code as you mentioned and Sorry but I have no grip on promises that's why i have to give you overview in callback's.